# incompatible types: int cannot be converted to String in an array

Tags: java

Can't figure out whats wrong. Cant really fine the same type of duplicate but maybe i missed it. Still really new so sorry if it is a duplicate .

Sorting_2.java:25: error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to String
                                Sorting sorting = new Sorting(lastName, firstName, age, insuranceCompany, roomNum);
                                                                                   ^
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
1 error

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Sorting
{
public String lastName;
public String firstName;
public int age;
public String insuranceCompany;
public int roomNum;

//public String toString()
//{
    //return name + "  " + population + "  " + state;
    //return String.format("%-13s %-17s %9d", lastName, firstName, age, insuranceCompany,roomNum);
//}

public Sorting(String l, String f, String i, int a, int r)
{
    lastName = l;
    firstName = f;
    age = a;
    insuranceCompany = i;
    roomNum = r;
} 


}

class lastNameComarator implements Comparator<Sorting>
{
public int compare(Sorting a, Sorting b)
{

    return a.lastName.compareToIgnoreCase(a.lastName);
}
}
class firstNameComparator implements Comparator<Sorting>
{
public int compare(Sorting a, Sorting b)
{
    return a.firstName.compareToIgnoreCase(b.firstName);
}
}
class insuranceCompanyComparator implements Comparator<Sorting>
{
public int compare(Sorting a, Sorting b)
{
    return a.insuranceCompany.compareToIgnoreCase(b.insuranceCompany);
}
}
class ageComparator implements Comparator<Sorting>
{
public int compare(Sorting a, Sorting b)
{
    if (a.age < b.age) return -1;
    else if (b.age < a.age) return 1; 
    else return 0;
}
}
class roomNumComparator implements Comparator<Sorting>
{
public int compare(Sorting a, Sorting b)
{
    if (a.roomNum < b.roomNum) return -1;
    else if (b.roomNum < a.roomNum) return 1;
    else return 0;
}
}
```

another program

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Sorting_2
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try
    {
        String fileName = args[0];
        ArrayList<Sorting> patient = new ArrayList<Sorting>();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner ( new File (fileName) );

        while (scan.hasNext())
        {
            String line = scan.nextLine();
            String[] tokens = line.split(",");

            String lastName = tokens[0];
            String firstName = tokens[1];
            int age = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]);
            String insuranceCompany = tokens[3];
            int roomNum = Integer.parseInt(tokens[4]);

            Sorting sorting = new Sorting(lastName, firstName, age, 
 insuranceCompany, roomNum);
            patient.add(sorting);
        }
        String comparisonType = args [1];
        if (comparisonType.equals("lastName"))
        {
            Collections.sort(patient, new lastNameComarator());
        }
        else if (comparisonType.equals("firstName"))
        {
            Collections.sort(patient, new firstNameComparator());
        }
        else if (comparisonType.equals("age"))
        {
            Collections.sort(patient,new ageComparator());
        }
        else if (comparisonType.equals("insuranceCompany"))
        {
            Collections.sort(patient, new insuranceCompanyComparator());
        }
        else if (comparisonType.equals("roomNum"))
        {
            Collections.sort(patient, new roomNumComparator());
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.printf("%-13s %-17s %-9s %-10s %9s%n", "lastName", "firstName", "age", "insuranceCompany", "roomNum");

        for(Sorting c : patient)
        {
            System.out.println(c);
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You have your arguments in the wrong order. It would be easier to discover if your arguments in the constructor had real variable names rather than single letters `public Sorting(String l, String f, String i, int a, int r)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of your constructor arguments is wrong. Your signature ends with two integers preceded by three strings; you need to swap `insuranceCompany` and `age`. Like,

```
Sorting sorting = new Sorting(lastName, firstName, insuranceCompany, age, roomNum);
```

Comment: Thank you I didn't know it have to be in a order like that.